# JavaFx 2.0 block game animation / code design

Tags: design-patterns, javafx-2

To keep my own coding skill up I have recently been building a version of [this game](https://web.archive.org/web/20181006184919/http://www.mindjolt.com:80/block-blaster.html)(Block blaster) in Java using JavaFx 2.0. As it was only for my benefit there was no real thought to software patterns or design and so all the game logic ended up in the GUI classes, which became more and more bloated as I added features. I finally decided to refactor the code base to separate the game logic and model from the presentation (GUI).

After some research I decided to use something like MVC or MVP. In doing so I decided that the animations (Block sliding up the game grid when fired, blocks flashing as they are removed from the game, etc) were to be part of the view layer.

The issue this causes is that when the user launchers a block and the controller tells the view to move the block it creates the JavaFx `timeline` for the animation and calls `timeline.play()`. Doing so does not cause the program flow to pause in the view while the animation takes place so the view method returns having only just started the animation meaning the controller then moves on to the checks to see if the the block has made a group of blocks and if so removes them before the move animation has got anywhere.

In the old (nasty) implementation I used the `timeline.onFinish` to call the block group check once the animation was done but as the `timeline` is now in the view and the check function in the controller I don't know how to put this in my new design.

Is there a way of waiting for the JavaFx animation to finish (without sleeping the application thread) or is there a different design pattern I should be using that would help avoid these problems?

**Code from controller**

```
public void fire()
{   
    //Get the current column the launcher is in.
    int x = launcher.getX(), startY = launcher.getY();
    //Find the next available block in the column.
    int endY;
    for(endY = h; endY > 0 && blockMap[endY - 1][x] == null; endY--){}

    //Create a new block of the same colour and location as that on the launcher.
    addBlock(x, launcher.getY(), getCurrentColourAndRotate());
    //Move the block in the GUI and model (this will trigger the animation in the GUI)
    moveBlock(x, startY, x, endY);

    //Remove any block groups that have been made.
    checkBlock(blockMap[endY][x]);
    //Remove any blocks now not connected to the top of the game grid
    removeUnconnectedBlocks();
}
```

**Screenshot of sample game**

[image: Sample game picture]
<sub>(source: [myhappygames.com](http://m2.myhappygames.com/files/pics/2/Block-Blaster-6-2787.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, so this was done in a hurry, but assuming that a Block is the square you press and Group is a collection of 3 or more adjacent Blocks with the same colour as in my drawing, then the trouble you are running into is that you are doing too much in the same method.

[image]

[image]

When you press a Block, you should notify your Controller. This should decide if this is part of a Group, and if so put the Group on fire? (I'm not familiar with the terminolgy). The Blocks in this Group should then be given a new state, for example ON_FIRE. The Model will notify all observers that these Blocks are now ON_FIRE. Once the View gets this information, you will do your ON_FIRE animation, collapse or whatever. Once this is completed which should correspond to the `timeLine.onFinnish`, you now call the next method in the Controller, for example `completedBurning`. This will now be responsible for cleaning up and indirectly triggering new things.

Hope this makes sense.

[image: Class diagram]

Comment: In the game I linked to instead of you clicking on a block to clear groups the user fires blocks out of a launcher at the bottom of the screen. Surly this means that the view can't do any initial animation and just passes this "fire block" command to the controller. The way I currently do this is the controller creates the block under the launcher and then moves it to the next free space. I then try and get the view to animate this view and this is where I am having problems as once the block is moved I need to check for groups but I can't seem to wait for the animation to finish.

Comment: The game I came to was Panda Jam. When you click on a block/square/cell and this is adjacent to at least to other Blocks, this group collapses. In thos game new Blocks are added at the bottom with short regular intervals, once a horizontal line is complete, everything moves up. Maybe you could give the name of the game and a screenshot to avoid onfusion, it seems there are more than one game there. I will add a screenshot of the game I thought you linked to... Either way, Id I understand correctly, you shold wait for the animation to complete, and them call a method on Controller to signal it.

Comment: I did include a link to the game in the original post but I have now added the name of the game alongside that and a screenshot. Sorry for the confusion caused. I should be able to adapt the UML and answers you have given me to my game and so I will mark this answer as accepted and if I come up with another question I will comment here again. Thank you for your help.